# What is the USB 3.0 Type-B SuperSpeed socket on my display for?

Tags: usb, display, usb-3, thunderbolt, lg-monitor

I just bought a new LG 34UC98-W screen which comes with a USB 3.0 Type-B SuperSpeed socket on the back along with two Type-A sockets.

The type A sockets are for connecting USB devices to a computer connected via Thunderbolt **but what is the Type-B SuperSpeed connector for?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the thunderbolt connection, you can also use the Type-B port to connect the monitor to the pc:

[image]
(from the [user's manual](http://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-34UC98-W#))

Comment: ugh. Beat me to that by 2 seconds. Have an upvote you magnificient ganker. Its worth adding you'd want to do that if the monitor is connected over DP